# What's a good way to perform cross-platform inter-thread notifications in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cross-platform

Scenario:
- My main (UI) thread (Thread "M") runs, and spins up a worker thread ("W") to control with some hardware.
- "W" wants to send progress notifications to "M" every so often.
- The notification-invocation can't block "W"... "W" needs to make the call and return immediately; "M" will process the notification async and not return anything to "W".
- "M" must notified by a callback running on thread "M".
- Must be able to pass data (don't worry about thread-safeness of data).

.NET has just such a facility in it's System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation class, but I'm wanting to create cross-platform code, not just .NET or even strictly Win32 (though my 1st platform is native c++ on Win32).

Using Boost would be a plus.

I've read this:
[Boost: Fire and forget asynchronous function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155311/boost-fire-and-forget-asynchronous-function-call)
but am wondering if there's a simpler want than to spin up additional helper threads.

Any ideas and/or links would be greatly appreciated!
-Dave

Comment: This is a very challenging set of requirements.  I am not sure it can all be done as specified. The snag is <em>"M" will process the notification async ... "M" must notified by a callback running on thread "M"</em>  I think that for this to be done, thread M needs to poll or otherwise occasionally yield so the notification code can run in the M thread.  To do what you specify, thread M needs to forcible interrupted by the notification and then, somehow resumed where it left off.  Theoretically possible - the OS does it all the time - but in user code?

Comment: @ravenspoint makes a good point, we really need more information about the structure of the program to answer this. It sounds like what you want is a main loop that processes events asynchronously.There are libraries that do this for you, [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/), [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), etc. (the list goes on an on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html) then you can use a [condition variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

- You have to setup a message list, which could be implemented, for example, as a linked list. Access to this list must always be protected by a mutex.
- When "W" wants to send an update to "M" it just adds the new data at the end of the message list.
- After appending to the message list, "W" can signal to "M" that there is new data using, for example, a semaphore.
- "M" can do whatever tasks it needs to do, and every so often can check the state of the semaphore. If the semaphore is in signaled state it can reset it and consume the messages from the list.

**Edit**: note that the requirement to use a mutex is optional. This would be the most common, most cross-platform friendly solution and that is why I put it in my example. If the requirement for the "W" thread to never block is the strongest requirement, then you can replace the list+mutex with a lock-free data structure, assuming you have one for your platform.

Comment: This solution is the most 'cross-platform' since mutex/sema are available on every multithreaded OS.

Comment: This solution would work in most cases.  It is probably the 'standard' way of doing such things.  However, it does not satisfy the requirements of the original question.  Because of the mutex on the message list, the worker thread can block and because the semaphore must be polled by the main thread, the notification is not processed asynchronously.  The original questioner is probably aware of this technique, and is asking for something different.

Comment: What about the requirement to process the notification in the main thread asynchronously?  That's the one I found hardest!  Your solution of polling the semaphore will work, but does not do what the question asked.

Comment: My interpretation of "M will process the notification async" is that M can go consume the message list from W at any time he wants, without synchronizing with when W writes to the list. Polling achieves that. Do you make a different interpretation?

Comment: Yes.  There are two approaches to poorly expressed requirements.  You can interpret them in the simplest easiest way and hope that is what the client meant.  Or you can use the strictest interpretation, knowing that your implementation will exceed or equal the clients needs.  Which way do you think makes for happy clients?

Comment: First of all, the OP is not my client, he is a fellow developer that I suspect will take the simplest approach that gets the job done. I asked you a simple question. The question was what is your "strictest" interpretation of this OP's requirement? Would you be so kind to share it so that we can discuss it?